# Virtualbox bridged adaptor not working

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vmware-workstation

I got a dedicated Windows server running at Hetzner.

But I would like to have a virtual Ubuntu server running using Virtualbox or vmware with the ability to ssh and view web-admin pages from programs installed from the outside.

I have no problem installing ubuntu server 16.04 in VB or VM. But all guides I'm seeing is telling me to change my network from NAT to bridged adaptor, if I want to be able to contact the server.

When I change the network and tell ubuntu to restart the network with:

**sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart**

It get stuck and it never restarts the network or anything.. just says:

Restarting networking (via systemctl): Networking.service

For a long time and then says failed..

If I reset the Virtual machine I get stuck while booting with:

*A start job is running for Raise network interfaces*

Don't know whats wrong..All guides looks easy enough, just change from NAS to bridged adaptor and then restart the network service..

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hetzner knows how to fix this.

Because Windows VM gives IP address to Linux VM in NAT mode. In bridge mode IP address will be given to Linux VM via Hetzner's DHCP service if it'll be possible.